# Obsolete flag after upvoting comment

Tags: discussion, support, comments, flagging

I upvoted someone else's comment and later edited the answer that it was commenting on, making the comment obsolete. It doesn't seem possible for me to flag the comment now, but is it still possible for another user to flag it as obsolete?

Comment: This is the comment that no longer makes sense with the way the answer reads now: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104122/is-there-a-name-for-spelling-differences-in-words-like-grey-gray-color-colou/104127#comment212019_104127 --It was responding to my assertion that an example I had provided was unique before I ultimately edited the example out as commentary which was out of scope for the question.

Comment: Having read back through your edits, I see the obsolescence and deleted the comment.

Comment: @simchona Hey, thanks.

Comment: Related feature request on MSO: [Allow flagging a comment after upvoting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you up-vote a comment, you cannot flag it anymore. Other users who didn't up-vote the comment can flag it for moderation attention, though.